# How many digits of an $n$ digit positive integer do I need to know to correctly guess the first $m$ digits of the $k$ th root of $n$.

Tags: roots, puzzle

Please help me solve this puzzle, which in my opinion only sounds tough:

How many digits (counting from the left) of an $n$ digit positive integer do I need to know to correctly guess the first $m$ digits of the $k$th ($k \geq 1$) root of $n$.

Comment: Roughly $mn/k$. There are algorithms which calculate the $k$th root of $n$, one digit at a time, and they split $n$ into groups of $k$ digits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm#Paper-and-pencil_nth_roots

Comment: @CarlHeckman: I do not see why $n$ comes into this in a substantial way: roughly $m/k$ looks more plausible.

Comment: Oops. One of my few errors. 8-) It should be $mk$ or so.